# Maximum standard deviation for a given set of real numbers

Tags: statistics, variance, standard-deviation

> Consider $5$ observations $0 \leq a \leq b \leq c \leq d \leq e \leq 100$. If $\sigma$ is the standard deviation then it is always less than or equal to 
> (a) $20$ $\qquad$ (b) $30$ $\qquad$ (c) $40$ $\qquad$ (d) $50$

---

Now I know that the formula for standard deviation(as taught to us, I do not know if there are any other formulae) is

= √(∑(ₖ)²-²)

where  is the mean of given data

On simplifying using given data,

25²=(∑(-)²)

I do not know how to proceed after this. My intuition says that if the last two numbers be 100 and the others be 0 standard deviation should be maximum(as it's 'spaced out' more, if that makes any sense). Then

² = 2400

but the answer is given as (d)50

Is the answer given wrong? Is there any inequality that would help in solving this question that I am not aware of? I tried using root mean square ≥ mean but that gives a lower bound not an upper bound.

Any help/hint would be appreciated

Comment: I MathJax'ed a bit. Please do the rest

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Look at the post [Maximum of the Variance Function for Given Set of Bounded Numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83046/maximum-of-the-variance-function-for-given-set-of-bounded-numbers), particularly the answer of Dilip. Your answer is *perfectly correct*, the option of $50$ is correct for this question but not optimal (which is exactly your point of confusion) because you have $5$ observations, which is an odd number. Using $N=5,c=100$ in Dilip's working gives $2400$ as the maximum variance, so you actually identified the best value.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Thank you!!

Comment: All your own good work, so it's nice to see it ratified. As a principle, remember that in multiple choice exams (I've set some of them, so I know this!) people purposely set non-optimal values to confuse people, as is the case here. When the variance is less than $\sqrt{2400}$, it is less than $50$ as well (and that's the only option!) but as it turns out students will be scratching their heads if they expect to obtain exactly $50$ as an upper bound somehow.

Comment: Note that is you used $\frac{1}{n-1}$ in the variance calculation then the maximum   (sample) standard deviation would be $\sqrt{3000} \approx 54.8$